Solve Large Scale Underdetermined Linear Equation with per Element Equality Constraint
I have the following system on $\boldsymbol{x}$:
$$ \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{0}, \quad \text{subject to} \; {x}_{i} = {v}_{i} \; \forall i \in \mathcal{V} $$
Where $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with $m < n$. It is a banded matrix (5-9 bands).
The set $\mathcal{V}$ is a sub set of indices to force equality values on $\boldsymbol{x}$.
The problem can be formulated as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{A} \\ \boldsymbol{E} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}} \\ \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{V}} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \boldsymbol{v} \end{bmatrix}
$$
Where:

$\boldsymbol{E} = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{I} \end{bmatrix}$.
$\mathcal{U} = \left\{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \right\} \setminus \mathcal{V}$.

I will post the way I solved it now. Just to share what I have tried.
I am after efficient methods which takes advantage of the structure of the problem.
Remark: Usually using direct solvers or iterative solvers on the extended equation above will yield the Least Squares solution. So if the right hand side vector is not in the range of the extended matrix in the left hand side the constraints won't hold.

In your answer, you don't solve $Ax=0$, but you minimize $|Ax|^2$. That is, you may end up with an $x$ that does not satisfy $Ax=0$. The question I would have would be whether the problem you have actually has a solution, or whether you're only interested in a least-squares-type solution?

@WolfgangBangerth, I wrote that my answer is the fastest thing I can do. In case there is such $\boldsymbol{x}$ they should match.

Do you know anything about the rank of A and [A;E]? I think this should be solvable without resorting to a minimization algorithm of any kind.

@Bort, I think it is reasonable to assume full column rank.

Here is a bit of a different suggestion. Instead of minimizing a variant of $x^TAx$ s.t. $x_i=v_i\, \forall i\in \mathcal{V}$ you could do the following:
You know already that your system has the form of $Mx=b$ after permutation and solving for the subset of variables in $\mathcal{V}$.
This means that $b$ must be in the column space of $M$ if you want to have a solution at all, otherwise there is no solution $x$.
However since $M$ is not full rank, you have infinite number of possible solutions for $x$. So let's pick one specifically with a convex cost function:
$$\underset{x}{\text{minimize}} \,\mathcal{J}(x) \\
\text{s.t.}\\ Mx=b$$
with e.g. $\mathcal{J}(x)=||x||_2$. With a convex cost function you will have a unique, global solution to your problem.
This can be also be written with a Lagrange multiplyer
$$\mathcal{L}(x)=||x||^2_2+\lambda^T (Mx-b) $$
and solved efficiently with gradient descent solver.

If you look at the code, I actually solved it, among other options, like I solved the Least Squares case just for the linear equation.

I added the answer I use in my code. I think it is similar to your idea.

no. instead of solving least square you should solve for a convex cost function with condition of the undertermined linear system. That way you will have a solution which acutally solves the original problem if $b$ is in column space of $M$. The cost function takes care of the undetermined variables.

Look at the other answer of mine. It doesn't solve LS problem.

Thanks for the suggestion and effort. +1.

Additional solution from my code at Edge Preserving Multi Scale Image Decomposition based on Local Extrema.
$$ \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{A}_{\mathcal{U}} & \boldsymbol{A}_{\mathcal{V}} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}} \\ \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{V}} \end{bmatrix} = \boldsymbol{0} $$
This implies that if the solution exists, it must obey:
$$ \boldsymbol{A}_{\mathcal{U}} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}} = - \boldsymbol{A}_{\mathcal{V}} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{V}} $$
From this equation one could extract $\boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}}$.
Remark: There is some cases to handle here. In case the matrix is not full rank. Hence it is advised to use a Linear LS solver which returns the Least Norm solution (See MATLAB's lsqminnorm()).

yes, lsqminnorm very likely does this under the hood. so then its fine. So my suggestion leaves the choice of the convex cost function to you. E.g. inf or l1 norm can also be interesting choices, depending on your problem.

General Approach
You can turn this into a problem that always has a solution by compressing the operator to the subspace orthogonal to the constraints. Let $c_i=1$ if $i\in\mathcal{V}$ and $c_i=0$ for $i\not\in\mathcal{V}$. Let $C=\operatorname{diag}(c)\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$. Then you can solve $(C+(I-C)A)u = Cv$. Taking into account $Cu=Cv$ this may be rewritten as $$(C+(I-C)A(I-C))u = Cv - (I-C)ACv.$$
If $A$ is symmetric positive semidefinite then $C+(I-C)A(I-C)$ is also symmetric psd. Then you can apply the conjugate method directly. As an example if $A\approx -\Delta$ with zero Neumann boundary conditions then $C+(I-C)A(I-C)$ is even positive definite for $c\ne 0$ (i.e. if you have at least one interpolation condition). In CG it's still cheaper to use the form $(C+(I-C)A)u = Cv$ since the mat-vec mult is cheaper, and if you initialize such that $Cu=Cv$ then you can show that the iterations are equivalent to the symmetric version. For the stopping criterion you can use $\|r^k\|^2 \leq \epsilon^2 \|b\|^2$, where typically $\epsilon \in [10^{-12}, 10^{-3}]$ depending on the condition number ($10^{-6}$ is probably alright). Here $b=Cv - (I-C)ACv$.
A GPU implementation with matrix-free products should be fairly fast - I can typically handle larger images in less than a second (for a related problm). If this is insufficient you should look into multigrid (much faster convergence for the lower frequency modes of the error) and domain decomposition (much nicer parallelization and memory locality - you will be memory bound for this problem so this helps a lot).

Continuous Setting
I looked at the paper by Levin. What you have is essentially a (color) inpainting problem. They have some form of weighted Laplacian and minimize a discrete counterpart of
$$\min_{u|_{\mathcal{V}} = v|_{\mathcal{V}}} E_p(u), \quad E_p(u) = 
\begin{cases}
\int_{\Omega} \|\nabla_W \Delta_W^k u\|^2, &\text{for } p = 2k+1, \\
\int_{\Omega} (\Delta_W^k u)^2, &\text{for } p = 2k.
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
The latter actually results (once you compute the Euler-Lagrange equations) in the following polyharmonic (color) inpainting problem (polyharmonic interpolation dates back to Harder, Duchon, Meinguet; in 1D this is just spline interpolation with degree $2p-1$):
\begin{alignat*}{2}
(-\Delta_W)^p u(x) &= 0, &\quad& x\in \Omega\setminus \mathcal{V}, \tag{2} \\
u(x) &= v(x), &\quad& x \in\mathcal{V}, \tag{3} \\
\partial_n\Delta^{\ell}_W u(x) &= 0, &\quad& x\in\partial\Omega, \quad 0\leq \ell \leq p-1. \tag{4}\\
\end{alignat*}
What you did not take into account is that this should be minimized over a space where the test functions vanish on the Dirichlet set $\mathcal{V}$. That is, the equation is valid on $\Omega\setminus\mathcal{V}$ and not on $\Omega$. In fact $\nabla\Delta_W^ku$ does not even have to be defined on $\mathcal{V}$. That's also where the $(I-C)$ part would pop out from since $C$ is an indicator function for $\mathcal{V}$ in the discrete setting, and $(I-C)$ is an indicator function for $\Omega\setminus\mathcal{V}$.
Let $A$ discretize the negated weighted Laplacian $-\Delta_W$ with zero Neumann conditions. Then the discrete counterpart of the above is $(C+(I-C)A^p)u = Cv$ as discussed. In their problem they have used $p=2$, but note that the condition number of $A^p$ is $\operatorname{cond}(A)^p$. You coul try $p=1$ but you will likely see the logarithmic singularities of the Laplacian kernel. So $p=2$ is probably good in terms of quality, albeit quite a bit slower than $p=1$. Fractional powers can be defined by using an eigendecomposition of $A$, but that's typically overkill and doesn't benefit you much in terms of quality.

Discrete Setting
Here's also the discrete setting directly derived from Levin's paper:
$$\min_{u|_{\mathcal{V}} = v|_{\mathcal{V}}} E_2(u), \quad E_2(u) = \sum_{i} \left(u_i - \sum_{j\in \mathcal{N}(i)} w_{ij} u_j\right)^2.$$
Setting $A_{ij} = w_{ij}$ you get $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and supposedly the weights are such that $w_{ij} = w_{ji}$ and $x^TAx \geq 0$. That is, $A$ is symmetric positive semi-definite. Let $c_i=1$ for $i\in\mathcal{V}$ and $c_i=0$ for $i\not\in\mathcal{V}$, and $C = \operatorname{diag}(c)\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$. We also know the orthonormal basis that for the orthogonal complement of $C$, namely the non-zero columns of $(I-C)$. Then we can rewrite
$$u = (C+(I-C))u = Cu + (I-C)u = Cv + (I-C)u.$$
This allows us to rewrite the problem as an unconstrained minimization problem:
\begin{align}
\min_{u|_{\mathcal{V}}= v|_{\mathcal{V}}}E_2(u) &=
\min_{Cu = Cv} \|Au\|^2 = \min_{Cu = Cv}u^TA^TAu \\
&= \min_{u\in\mathbb{R}^n} (Cv+(I-C)u)^TA^TA(Cv+(I-C)u) \\
&=
\min_{u\in\mathbb{R}^n} u^T(I-C)A^TA(I-C)u + 2u^T(I-C)A^TACv + v^TCA^TACv
\end{align}
Taking the gradient w.r.t. $u$ leads to:
$$\nabla E_2(u) = 2(I-C)A^TA(I-C)u + 2(I-C)A^TACv.$$
Then setting to zero leads to:
$$(I-C)A^TA(I-C)u = -(I-C)A^TACv.$$
Since $Cu=Cv$ we can add it to both sides:
$$(C+(I-C)A^TA(I-C))u = Cv-(I-C)A^TACv.$$
And you can substitute $Cv$ with $Cu$ in $(I-C)A^TACv$ in order to move it back to the left side:
$$(C+(I-C)A^TA)u = Cv.$$
Finally, if $A$ is symmetric, then $A^T=A$ and you can rewrite this as:
$$(C+(I-C)A^2)u = Cv.$$
Apply CG to the above, where the only thing that you need to make sure is that $u^0$ agrees with $v$ on $\mathcal{V}$ (i.e. the constraints have to be satisfied in the very first iteration, then the remaining iterations turn out as if you were using the symmetric matrix).

Derivation of the Euler-Lagrange Equations
I will use $u|_{\mathcal{V}} = f|_{\mathcal{V}}$ here since I want to use $v$ for the test function.
To get from $(1)$ to $(2),(3),(4)$ you can proceed by first defining the bilinear functional (wlog I will take the case where $p=2k+1$ but the other one is analogous):
$$B(v,u) = \int_{\Omega}\nabla \Delta^k v \cdot \nabla \Delta^k u$$.
Let us take the directional derivative of $E(u) = B(u,u)$ w.r.t. the function $v$:
\begin{align}
\partial_v E(u) &= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{B(u+\epsilon v, u+\epsilon v)-B(u,u)}{\epsilon} \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{B(u,u) + \epsilon B(u,v) + \epsilon B(v,u) + \epsilon^2 B(v,v)-B(u,u)}{\epsilon} \\
&= B(u,v) + B(v,u) = 2B(v,u).
\end{align}
You want to bring this to some form $\partial_v E(u) = 2B(v,u) = \int_{\Omega} v \nabla E(u)$ in order to find the functional derivative $\nabla E(u)$. You can do so by using the divergence theorem and the product rule multiple times. More specifically:
\begin{align*}
B(v,u) &= \int_{\Omega}\nabla \Delta^k v \cdot \nabla \Delta^k u = 
-\int_{\Omega} \Delta^k v \Delta^{k+1} u + \int_{\Omega} \nabla\cdot (\Delta^k v \nabla \Delta^{k} u) \\
&= -\int_{\Omega} \nabla\cdot\nabla \Delta^{k-1} v \Delta^{k+1} u + \int_{\partial\Omega} \Delta^k v \partial_n \Delta^k u \\
&= \int_{\Omega} \nabla \Delta^{k-1} v \cdot \nabla \Delta^{k+1} u 
- \int_{\Omega} \nabla\cdot(\nabla \Delta^{k-1}v\Delta^{k+1}u) + \int_{\partial\Omega} \Delta^k v \partial_n \Delta^k u \\
&= \int_{\Omega} \nabla \Delta^{k-1} v \cdot \nabla \Delta^{k+1} u
- \int_{\partial\Omega} \partial_n \Delta^{k-1}v\Delta^{k+1}u + 
\int_{\partial\Omega} \Delta^k v \partial_n \Delta^k u \\
&= \ldots \\
&= \int_{\Omega} v (-\Delta)^{2k+1} u + \int_{\partial\Omega} \Delta^k v \partial_n \Delta^k u + 
\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}\int_{\partial\Omega} \Delta^{\ell} v \partial_n \Delta^{2k-\ell}u - \partial_n \Delta^{\ell} v \Delta^{2k-\ell}u.
\end{align*}
Now if you choose to specify $\partial_n \Delta^{\ell} u = 0$ for $0\leq \ell \leq 2k$ (since $p=2k+1$ in this case) you get rid of all boundary terms involving $\partial_n\Delta^{\ell}u$. Meanwhile, the tests functions must also satisfy $\partial_n\Delta^{\ell}v = 0$ which makes the other term also zero. Ultimately you are left with $B(v,u) = \int_{\Omega} v (-\Delta)^p u$, thus the functional derivative is $(-\Delta)^pu$. Finally need to take into account $u|_{\mathcal{V}} = f|_{\mathcal{V}}$. Then you get the condition $v|_{\mathcal{V}} = 0$ and the PDE is valid only on the set $\Omega\setminus \mathcal{V}$. Note that $u|_{\mathcal{V}} = f|_{\mathcal{V}}$ is not really a boundary condition (at least not for $p>1$) - it acts just as an interpolation constraint on the interior of the domain. So ultimately you get (2), (3), (4). As long as $\mathcal{V}$ is non-empty you have a unique solution (provided the domain boundary $\partial\Omega$ and $f$ are sufficiently regular).

I don't see why this trick is different from assuming a specific permutation.

@Royi Because of the $(I-C)$ matrix in front of $A$. I am not just doing $Au = Cv$ and then $A(I-C+C)u = Cv$ and $A(I-C)u = Cv-Cu = 0$. This is non-symmetric and is not guaranteed to have a solution. $(C+(I-C)A)u = Cv$ is equivalent to a symnetric system as discussed and always has a solution. No squaring of the condition number either.

@Royi On further analysis I think you misread the paper. I believe that the $(I-C)$ was supposed to be there to begin with. See the edit of my answer.

Appreciate the deep answer and the effort. I asked the question in a general context, not only that paper.  Anyhow, specifically for the paper (Colorization Using Optimization) model, the matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ is neither symmetric nor positive definite.

@Royi But $A^TA$ is symmetric positive semi-definite. So the only thing that would change is that you can't write $A^2$, but you have $A^TA$. For the general context - if you are setting up interpolation problems with no solution then there is likely something wrong with your modelling. But as you saw above (the discrete setting part), at least for the minimization the problem always has a solution due to this $(I-C)$ popping out in front of $A^TA$. Then clearly $(I-C)A^TACv$ is in the range of $(I-C)A^TA$.

My current approach is to make this a Least Squares problem:
$$\begin{align}
\arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \begin{aligned} 
{x}_{i} & = {v}_{i}, \; \forall i \in \mathcal{V} \\
\end{aligned}
\end{align}$$
It is equivalent to:
$$\begin{align}
\arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \quad & \frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{B} \boldsymbol{x} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \begin{aligned} 
{x}_{i} & = {v}_{i}, \; \forall i \in \mathcal{V} \\
\end{aligned}
\end{align}$$
Where $\boldsymbol{B} = \boldsymbol{A}^{T} \boldsymbol{A}$, is a Symmetric Positive Semi Definite (SPSD) Matrix.
Given a Permutation Matrix allows to order the elements:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}} \\ \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{V}} \end{bmatrix} = \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{x} $$
Since for any Permutation Matrix $ \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{P}^{T} = \boldsymbol{P}^{T} \boldsymbol{P} = \boldsymbol{I} $ then:
$$ \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{B} \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{P}^{T} \left( \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{B} \boldsymbol{P}^{T} \right) \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{x} = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}}^{T} & \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{V}}^{T} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{B}_{\mathcal{U}} & \boldsymbol{C} \\ \boldsymbol{C} & \boldsymbol{B}_{\mathcal{V}} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}} \\ \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{V}} \end{bmatrix} $$
The permutation matrix partitioned to problem into 2 sub sets. Since the constraints define $\boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{V}}$, one can only solve the above for $\boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}}$:
$$\begin{align}
\arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}}} \quad & \frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}}^{T} \boldsymbol{B}_{\mathcal{U}} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}} + \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{v}}^{T} \boldsymbol{C} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \begin{aligned} 
{x}_{i} & = {v}_{i} \; \forall i \in \mathcal{V} \\
\end{aligned}
\end{align}$$
Hence the problem becomes constraint free:
$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}}} \frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}}^{T} \boldsymbol{B}_{\mathcal{U}} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}} + \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{v}}^{T} \boldsymbol{C} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{U}} $$
Since $\boldsymbol{B}_{\mathcal{U}}$ is a SPSD matrix the problem is convex hence the solution is given where the gradient vanishes:
$$ \boldsymbol{B}_{\mathcal{U}} \hat{\boldsymbol{x}}_{\mathcal{U}} = - \boldsymbol{C} \boldsymbol{x}_{\mathcal{V}} $$
So the problem is transformed into a linear system of SPSD matrix with no constraints.
Yet the condition number is probably higher (I am not it is squared as it is a a sub set of of the columns / rows of $\boldsymbol{B}$).
Remark: The LS formulation will hold the constraints for any solution. As opposed to the direct extended linear system from the question post.
I implemented code of this method vs. the direct solution as above.
The matrix is based on the definition in Build the Affinity Matrix of Edge Preserving Multiscale Image Decomposition based on Local Extrema.
The image size was 250 x 250. The size of of the set $\left| \mathcal{V} \right| = 13747$.
The results I got, using Julia:

Direct Solvers: Solving the original formulation (Direct in the cdoe) problem was ~50% faster from the LS (LS in the code).
Iterative Solvers:

LS Solution based on Conjugate Gradient:

Error (Max Absolute vs. Direct Solution): 0.000047055766.
Run Time: 8.86836 [Sec].


Direct Solution based on LSMR:

Error (Max Absolute vs. Direct Solution): 0.086388343173.
Run Time: 4.27441 [Sec].


Direct Solution based on LSQR:

Error (Max Absolute vs. Direct Solution): 0.001536492862.
Run Time: 7.62469 [Sec].


Direct Solution based on CRAIG:

Error (Max Absolute vs. Direct Solution): 0.000066854811.
Run Time: 9.38470 [Sec].


Direct Solution based on CGLS:

Error (Max Absolute vs. Direct Solution): 0.000083813606.
Run Time: 8.60961 [Sec].





All iterative solvers are form Krylov.jl with the default settings.
Run time measured by BenchmarkTools.jl using @belapsed.
Remark: I shared my tryout in case it will assist someone. Yet I'm after a better, if there is, solution to the problem.

The code is available on my StackExchange Computational Science GitHub Repository (Look at the ComputationalScience\Q44552 folder).

This is actually equivalent to the $I-C$ I mentioned, you are right. But it is not equivalent to your original question. More generally, if you have $V^Tx = v$ you can construct bases $Q_{\ker}, Q_{\ker^{\perp}}$ for the kernel of $V^T$ and its orth compl. and $$x=x_{\ker} + x_{\ker^{\perp}} = Q_{\ker}z + Q_{\ker^{\perp}}y.$$
Then $V^Tx = V^Tx_{\ker^{\perp}} = v$ and $$\min_{V^Tx = v} x^TBx = \min_{z} z^TQ_{\ker}^TBQ_{\ker}z + 2z^TQ_{\ker}^TBx_{\ker^{\perp}} + x_{\ker^{\perp}}^TBx_{\ker^{\perp}}$$ results in $$Q_{\ker}^TBQ_{\ker}z= -Q_{\ker}^TBQ_{\ker^{\perp}}(V^TQ_{\ker^{\perp}})^{+}v.$$

@lightxbulb, I am not sure I got the what you wrote. I also don't understand the advantage in the $\boldsymbol{C}$ trick. If you square $\boldsymbol{A}$, why not use the approach I posted?

I figured that the $C$ trick is the same as your permutation mathemaically, but both are not equivalent to your original question. The only benefit is that if you have a structured matrix (e.g. standard Laplacian), the $C$ does not modify its structure and is cheaper to store (1bit per index). As far as squaring $A$ goes - my point was that you don't always have to (in the Levin paper you do have to due to how they chose $A$ though afaik). E.g. $\min_{u|{\mathcal{V}} = v|{\mathcal{V}}}u^TAu$ would solve the problem $(C+(I-C)A)u = Cv$. Which of those you need depends on your goals of course.

It is the LS solution to the problem. It surely gives different solutions to some cases of $\boldsymbol{A}$ (Trivial case if $\boldsymbol{A}$ is SPD). I wonder what other cases will they be different.

Suppose you had $A\approx -\Delta$ then $A^TA\approx \Delta^2$. One solves the harmonic equation, while the other solves the biharmonic equation. The difference is pretty large in terms of results and properties (e.g. min-max principle, smoothness, singularities, etc.) as well as runtime. By minimizing $u^TA^TAu$ you are solving a different problem than $u^TAu$ (this results in $(A+A^T)u$ as gradient). Here's another example $A$ being orthogonal, then $A^TA=I$. Take the DCT/DST/DFT interpolation problem as an example of this, the $A^TA$ case is useless there. So it is quite different.

You're talking in general. Also the difference is not between $\boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}$ to $\boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}$. It is the case of $\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{0}$ to the minimization of ${ \left| \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} \right|}_{2}^{2}$.

$$E(x)=|Ax|^2 = x^TA^TAx \implies \nabla E(x) = 2A^TAx$$
$$E(x) = x^TAx\implies \nabla E(x) = (A+A^T)x.$$
These are different problems. If you have equality constraints $M^Tx = b$, $\min_{M^Tx=b}E(x)$ then this becomes $$\begin{bmatrix}B & M \ M^T & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \ \lambda\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \ b\end{bmatrix}$$ with $B=2A^TA$ or $B=A+A^T$.

To be sure, I mentioned the gradient because outside of any constraints you would have set $\nabla E = 0$, turning $\min_x x^TAx$ into $(A+A^T)x=0$ which is $Ax=0$ if $A$ is symmetric, so the difference is between $x^TAx$ and $x^TA^TAx$. More generally, if $A$ is square and symmetric, then $Ax=b$ (i.e. $\nabla E(x) =0$ for $E(x) = x^TAx - 2x^Tb$) is equivalent to $\min_x |Ax-b|^2$ if $b$ is in the range of $A$. However, the moment you add constraints that are not entirely in the kernel of $A$ this changes, and you get different problems (or if $b\not\in ran(A)$, or if $A$ is not symmetric).
